# Plotting graph in Julia with Float64 error

Tags: julia

```
using Plots
α = 1
γ = 1.5

y(x) = -α(1-(γ*x)^(2))*exp(-0.5*γ*x^(2))
plot(y,-3,3)
```

I have no idea how to solve this error.

```
MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
 1. y(::Float64)@Local: 2
 2. (::Base.var"#62#63"{RecipesPipeline.var"#7#8"{Symbol},typeof(Main.workspace315.y)})(::Float64)@operators.jl:875
 3. (::PlotUtils.var"#27#29"{Base.var"#62#63"{Base.var"#62#63"{RecipesPipeline.var"#7#8"{Symbol},typeof(Main.workspace315.y)},RecipesPipeline.var"#9#10"{Symbol}}})(::Float64)@adapted_grid.jl:46
 4. _broadcast_getindex_evalf@broadcast.jl:648[inlined]
 5. _broadcast_getindex@broadcast.jl:621[inlined]
 6. getindex@broadcast.jl:575[inlined]
 7. copy@broadcast.jl:876[inlined]
 8. materialize(::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{1},Nothing,PlotUtils.var"#27#29"{Base.var"#62#63"{Base.var"#62#63"{RecipesPipeline.var"#7#8"{Symbol},typeof(Main.workspace315.y)},RecipesPipeline.var"#9#10"{Symbol}}},Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}})@broadcast.jl:837
 9. #adapted_grid#26(::Int64, ::Float64, ::typeof(PlotUtils.adapted_grid), ::Any,
    ::Tuple{Float64,Float64})@adapted_grid.jl:57
 10. adapted_grid(::Any, ::Tuple{Float64,Float64})@adapted_grid.jl:16
 11. _scaled_adapted_grid(::Function, ::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Int64, ::Int64)@user_recipe.jl:353
 12. macro expansion@user_recipe.jl:293[inlined]
 13. apply_recipe(::AbstractDict{Symbol,Any}, ::Function, ::Number,
     ::Number)@RecipesBase.jl:283
    
 14. _process_userrecipes!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any)@user_recipe.jl:36
 15. recipe_pipeline!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any)@RecipesPipeline.jl:70
 16. _plot!(::Plots.Plot, ::Any, ::Any)@plot.jl:208
 17. #plot#154@plot.jl:91[inlined]
 18. plot(::Any, ::Any, ::Any)@plot.jl:85
 19. top-level scope@Local: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

short answer: the function should be defined as:

```
y(x) = -α * (1 - (γ * x)^2) * exp(-0.5γ * x^2)
```

The longer answer: the problem is not with the plotting because calling the `y` function would yield a similar error message. To answer the "how " to solve the error, I recommend testing the code bit by bit.
While Julia automatically understands a multiplication between a float and a variable (like the `0.5γ`), Julia understood that you wanted to use α as a function and because α is an integer, it raised the error.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you so much! That is why it works when I change the variables into numbers. Just a simple mistake!

Comment: If you feel that is it the correct answer, feel free to select it. 

Comment: Yeah `5x` and `5(x)` being multiplication but `x5` being a different variable and `x(5)` attempting function call is why I never use multiplication shorthand and lowkey hope it's deprecated one day.